# What does the word before = do?

Tags: java

What does the `ThisBit` in the following line of code do?

```
String Plaintext = sc.nextLine(), ThisBit = "";
```

If the `String` is called `Plaintext`, why do I need the `ThisBit` at the end?

Comment: It's just creating another String variable named `ThisBit` and assigning it to an empty string

Comment: It's equivalent to `String Plaintext = sc.nextLine(); String ThisBit="";`

Comment: `ThisBit` is called an identifier or variable name.  That's all it is.  It's a bit weird that the code doesn't use the regular Java code conventions and start with a lower case letter, which would make the code a bit more readable.

Comment: May I add, it’s considered poor style, though opinions differ. I think that most would prefer to write it as in @Eran’s comment, on two lines.

Comment: You can declare two variables at the same line using the `,` instead of `String Plaintext = sc.nextLine(); String ThisBit=" ";` that's a shorthand only, but the two ways are valid variables declarations in java.
Also it is a poor Style

Comment: @Eran If I am already assigning it to the String called Paintext, why do I need a new blank string?

Comment: You don't. It's your decision if you want or not.

Comment: Whoever wrote this piece of code probably needs that second String variable for some purpose.

Comment: @user11900011 Here you don't assign `ThisBit` variable to `PlainText`, what does `PlainText` does is reading a value from the scanner and store it, while `ThisBit` is another empty string that doesn't related to `PlainText`

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**:

`ThisBit` is the name of the second `String` variable you declare.

**Slightly longer answer**:

```
String Plaintext = sc.nextLine(), ThisBit="";
```

is equivalent to

```
String Plaintext = sc.nextLine();
String ThisBit = "";
```

The first String variable is assigned a value you're reading from a Scanner. The second variable is assigned an empty String value.

Comment: Why does it need to assign an empty string if the scanner is assigned to the first String which was just created to store the Scanner input?

Comment: @user11900011 Whoever write that code may want to do some manipulation on strings that needs to add letters or words to that empty string to compare it later.

Comment: @user11900011 : I don't know where and how the 'ThisBit' variable is used, so I can't tell you why it needs to be created and/or assigned an empty String. If you just want to read some Scanner input, there is no need to declare a second variable in this plaace. However, I don't know what the rest of the program does. So the variable might very well still be needed. (In any case, I'd suggest you declare the variables on second line. It is a bit more verbose but IMO quite a bit easier to read).

Comment: @Abdel-Raouf That’s one likely possibility. Another is that the coder was in a bad habit of declaring all variables up front and always giving them initial values. Perhaps the initial value is not needed at all. Without the full code we cannot tell.

Answer (score 1):

in java, **we can declare multiple variables in one line**

your code spinet is one of this example ... here `Plantext` and `ThisBit` both variable declare as String type and also initialize with there inite value...

but according to Java Coding Guidelines "**Declaring multiple variables in a single declaration could cause confusion about the types of variables and their initial values**" *[i think you face this problem]*

In general, you should declare each variable on its own line with an explanatory comment regarding its role. While not required for conformance with this guideline, this practice is also recommended in the Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language.

for more reading     [declare more than one variable per declaration](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2133373&seqNum=2)

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it need to assign an empty string if the scanner is assigned to the first String which was just created to store the Scanner input ?

Here in this code if i find that value of a character in the String Variable i read it from the scanner not equal to a `+`, i will add it to the empty string to get the final shape of the string i want.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String count = scanner.next();
    String temp = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < count.length(); i++){ 
        if(!String.valueOf(count.charAt(i)).equals("+")){
            temp += String.valueOf(count.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Comment: Though hypothetical it’s a nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here **ThisBit** is nothing but another String type variable which is referring empty string.

You may declare multiple variable of same type in single like separated by '**,**'.

In your case you have declared **two** String type variable, **Plaintext** and **ThisBit**.

Hope this will help you.